# UDP Broadcast python programming

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi3, broadcast

I was asked to broadcasting a message among set of raspberry pies

I want to  create the program that sends a broadcast of a message alert to all the nodes that are on the network and I want each station that receives the message must transmit it to other stations on the networks it is connected except the sender to spread the message.

I created the client.py and the server.py , but I don't know how to make the station re-transmit the message to all except the sender one .
its the first time I am creating a project in networking programming in python.
[CODING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwC1F.png)
IS ATTACHED

Comment: Please edit a [mre] of your code _as text_ into your question.

Comment: Beware of the broadcast storm! If you have a network with multiple paths (a loop in the topology, not a proper tree), this algorithm will spread the message A->B->C->A->B-> ... and also A->C->B->A->C->B ...

Comment: @barny- I was sharing code as text but is was showing so many errors! that's why I attached the picture